# Angular routing doesn't work when URL typed directly

Tags: iis, angular9

I've written a CMS in angular which uses the same component for every page, with the content being driven by the url path.

The routing looks like this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '**', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about/:name', component: HomeComponent },
])
```

This works fine when I run it locally in node but when I copy the dist files up to an IIS webserver there's a problem with the routing.

The links direct correctly to the right URL and the pages load fine this way, but entering the URL manually gives a 404.

I would have thought the routing would handle this, and it does when run locally, just not on the IIS server.

Any suggestions as to why this works locally but not on IIS?

Comment: Try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: You get a 404 error when you manually enter the url, and using failed request tracing can view what caused the 404 error, which will help you solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, although I meant, what is failed request tracing?

Comment: I Googled it; failed request tracing requires an IIS update, which I'm not in a position to do. Are there any potential Angular solutions?